# analytic integral

Tags: integration

I know this integral evaluates to 1 by using numerical techniques. Can it be done analytically ?

$$ \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\infty \frac{2}{\sqrt{2y+1}\sqrt{2 \pi}}  \exp \left( -y-\frac{1}{2} \right) dy $$

Comment: Try substituting $y+\frac12 = t^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
u=y+\frac12, \qquad du=dy,\qquad 2y+1=2u 
$$
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-1/2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2y+1}} e^{-(y+(1/2))} \, dy = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2u}} e^{-u}\,du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty u^{-1/2} e^{-u}\,du.
$$

The Gamma function is
$$
\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty u^{\alpha-1} e^{-u} \, du
$$
and its value at $\alpha=1/2$ is the integral above.  It is well known that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$.  I won't be surprised if the way that is proved is already an existing answer on stackexchange.  If not, maybe we should put it here.

The value you seek is therefore $1$.

Comment: Very helpful. +1. Thanks !